# How do i solve the exception of missing dll ? The dll file is in the directory

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll

This line:

```
Boolean bl = InitializeDirectX(mypb);
```

And the InitializeDirectX method that use DirectX:

```
public Boolean InitializeDirectX(PictureBox pb)
        {
            DispMode = Manager.Adapters[Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter].CurrentDisplayMode;
            D3Dpp = new PresentParameters();
            D3Dpp.BackBufferFormat = DispMode.Format;
            D3Dpp.PresentFlag = PresentFlag.LockableBackBuffer;

            D3Dpp.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
            D3Dpp.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.One; //wait for vertical sync. Synchronizes the painting with
            //monitor refresh rate for smoooth animation
            D3Dpp.Windowed = true; //the application has borders

            try
            {
                D3Ddev = new Device(Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter, DeviceType.Hardware, pb.Handle,
                                                                           CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, D3Dpp);
                D3Ddev.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format;
                D3Ddev.RenderState.Lighting = false;
                D3Ddev.RenderState.CullMode = Cull.CounterClockwise;

                backTexture = TextureLoader.FromStream(D3Ddev, mymem);
                scannedCloudsTexture = new Texture(D3Ddev, 512, 512, 1, Usage.Dynamic, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default);

                //sprite is used to draw the texture
                D3Dsprite = new Sprite(D3Ddev);

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The exception is thrown on the line:

```
Boolean bl = InitializeDirectX(mypb);
```

The exception is FileNotFoundException:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in My Weather Station.exe

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

And the file Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dll does exist in the directory that i see of the file in the references. I also don't see in the references on this dll any yellow or something state that the file is missing.

And i didn't have the exception before so just like that something changed in the dll file ?

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
  _HResult=-2147024770
  _message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
  HResult=-2147024770
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
  Source=My Weather Station
  FileName=Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dll
  FusionLog=""
  StackTrace:
       at mws.ScanningClouds.InitializeDirectX(PictureBox pb)
       at mws.ScanningClouds.ScanClouds_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\myprog.cs:line 179
  InnerException:
```

Line 179 is:

```
Boolean bl = InitializeDirectX(mypb);
```

And if some dependencies inside the dll are missing not sure why, how can i find wich ones and if at all ?

Udate:

This is the reference in the dotPeek of the file DirectXDirect3DX.dll

[image: dotPeek Reference]

And in my project:

[image: Reference in project]

I didn't understand the notepad part in T.S solution.

UPDATE

This is the references in my project file:

```
<Reference Include="AviFile">
      <HintPath>C:\Temp\avifilewrapper\aviFileWrapperDemo_src\AviDemo\bin\Debug\AviFile.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.DirectX, Version=1.0.2902.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Temp\radarscan\dlls\DLL'S\Microsoft.DirectX.DLL</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D, Version=1.0.2902.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Temp\radarscan\dlls\DLL'S\Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.DLL</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX, Version=1.0.2909.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Temp\radarscan\dlls\DLL'S\Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.DLL</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NumericComparer">
      <HintPath>C:\Temp\csnsort\csnsort_src\NumericComparer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Speech" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="unfreez_wrapper, Version=1.0.4362.38939, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\New folder\Unfreez\unfreez_wrapper\Release\unfreez_wrapper.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ZedGraph">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Appz\zedgraph_dll_v515_1\zedgraph_dll_v515\zedgraph_dll_v5.1.5\ZedGraph.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ZedGraph.Web">
```

Comment: Check dependencies - download application called `dotPeek`. Install and run it. Load your dll and see references. Now, open your project file in notepad, find all info about reference to your dll and paste it into your question. Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand the notepad part. I added two screenshots to my question.  What is the project file you mean ? My project name cs file ? or visual studio solution file ?

Comment: @Daniel: T.S. meant that you should open your project file (`.csproj`) in a text editor and look for the part where assembly names / references are mentioned. Then copy & paste that whole part of the project file into your question. The reason behind this is that looking at the project file sometimes is more telling than looking at references in VS.

Comment: More things to check: **1.** Are you perhaps missing (the right version of) `Microsoft.VisualC`? It appears that you would need to have the right Visual C++ runtime / redistributable installed. **2.** Have you installed (a recent version of) DirectX, and a recent/matching version of these SDK DLLs you're using? **3.** Have you tried compiling for both 32-bit and 64-bit?

Comment: The problem is my directx dll files are old they are version: 1.1.4322 and i can't find a way to install directx 9 or something on windows 8.1 pro i need this dll version to my project. I can upload my project or this form/class to some site so maybe you can see it.

Comment: As stakx said, I was asking to paste reference part from your project file because there could be different flags, like exact version, etc. So, you may reverence one version and while you have the dll, it may be not the version your project looking for. Now that you see references in dotPeek - see if you have all DLLs listed there

Comment: do you run your IDE "as administrator"? - try that and do "clean project/solution"

Answer (score 0):

Probably component or part of `Directx` are not installed on your machine. Installing `DirectX` on your machine would resolve the issue.

Comment: How do i install directx on windows 8.1 pro ? I saw that it should be via windows update but i don't have any updates.